# How do I draw two-colored diagonal background?

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, brush, diagonal

How do I draw two-colored diagonal background?
I want colors to be separated by diagonal of container.
I want diagonal to be preserved after resizing of container.

I have two categories of rows in my DataGrid dustinguished by colors. Few rows has both categories so I want to set their background like above.

Comment: I tried LinearGradientBrush, but it can't be set as diagonal.

Comment: @WaldemarGałęzinowski `LinearGradientBrush` can be set as a diagonal... see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0290__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/LinearGradientBrushExamples.htm) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a `DrawingBrush`. Here is an example for the background of a `Canvas`, but it can be used for the background of anything.

```
    <Canvas Margin="182,229,197,43">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <DrawingBrush>
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Aquamarine" Geometry="M 1,1 L 0,1 0,0 1,1"/>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Blue" Geometry="M 0,0 L 1,1 1,0 0,0"/>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
```

Resizing is not a problem as you can see in the attached pictures.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pair of stretched path objects to create the "background", then overlay whatever else you want over the top. The boundary between the two coloured regions will stay fixed on the diagonal, whatever size of the grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Path Stretch="Fill"  Data="M 0,0 L 0,1 L 1,0 L 0,0" Fill="Blue" />
    <Path Stretch="Fill"  Data="M 1,1 L 0,1 L 1,0 L 1,1" Fill="Red" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" FontSize="72" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.ZIndex="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer since I missed the part about resizing concerns. +1

Comment: @ChrisW. Your answered seems fine, I think you just need to apply the brush to something that is dynamically sized instead of a static-sized rectangle :)